# Bridging a serial input signal from an Arduino to a Raspberry Pi

Tags: c++, linux, arduino, serial-port, raspberry-pi3

I try out the [eHealth-Kit by Cooking Hacks](https://www.cooking-hacks.com/documentation/tutorials/ehealth-biometric-sensor-platform-arduino-raspberry-pi-medical.)

So for now everything works fine. The code compiled successfully (C++) and I got some output when I run the app.

My problem is that I don't have the connection bridge shield to connect the serial ports of my Arduino and Raspberry.

I run my code on the Raspberry Pi and connect my eHealth sensors with the Arduino.
The thing I would like to do is to bridge Arduino and Raspberry via an USB type B cable.

I already searched for some tutorials on the internet. But I just found examples to turn on a LED coded on the Raspberry.

But I would like to bridge the incoming serial signal to the ports of my Raspberry because the eHealth-API coded by Cooking Hacks is listening to those ports.

used hardware:

- Arduino Uno
- Raspberry Pi 3 with Jessie 4.4
- USB cable type B
- eHealth sensor shield
- some sensors (spo2, blood pressure, ecg)

Any suggestions? Is it possible to easily connect the ports?
Lookng forward to hearing from you.

Thanks in advance! :)